# CAML Query Returning too many rows

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to build  CAML Query that pulls items from a SharePoint 2013 list with a "Status" value of "COMPLETED", but instead this query returns all list items regardless of the value of "Status". Any ideas why this is happening?

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    '<View>' +
    '<Query>' +
    '<Where>' +
    '<Geq>' +
    '<FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/>' +
    '<Value Type=\'Text\'><COMPLETED/></Value>' +
    '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit>' +
    '<Geq>' +
    '</Where>' +
    '</Query>' +
    '</View>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you are putting right status value in "Value" tag - no typos, no need to do extra uppercase or lowercase. Use it just like it  stored in SP.
Also try to use "Contains" element in your query:

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    '<View>' +
    '<Query>' +
    '<Where>' +
    '<Contains>' +
    '<FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/>' +
    '<Value Type=\'Text\'>COMPLETED</Value>' +
    '<Contains>' +
    '</Where>' +
    '</Query>' +
    '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit>' +
    '</View>');
```

Good luck!